# Show that $D_xf(0,0)$ exists for all $x$ although $f$ is not even continuous at $(0,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2 }: x>0, 0<y<x^2\}$.

Let $f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is not in $A$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\in A$. Show that $D_xf(0,0)$ exists for all $x$ although $f$ is not even continuous at $(0,0)$.

### My attempt:

Not sure how to tackle this one... Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Additionally to Thomas's hint have a look at the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{n^2}, \frac{1}{n}\right)_n$.

Comment: $D_xf(0,0)$ for all $x$ makes no sense.